# Can't visit object member variable in another object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I defined two classes: `Player` and `HelloWorldLayer`. In `HelloWorldLayer`, I defined a member variable: `NSArray *bullets`. In `Player`, I defined a member variable `HelloWorldLayer *hwLayer`. Now in one of `Player`'s function, I want to visit bullets with `hwLayer.bullets`, but it doesn't work and gives a compile error. I've attached screen shots - can anyone help me determine what's wrong?

[image: Player.h]

[image: Player.m]

[image: HelloWorldLayer.h]

[image: HelloWorldLayer.me]

[image: Function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forward-declare `HelloWorldLayer` in the header

```
@class HelloWorldLayer;
```

It lets you declare _hwlayer instance variable. However, it is not sufficient to start using its properties: but you must import the header that contains `HelloWorldLayer` into the .m file that references `bullets`.

Alternatively, you can use the square bracket syntax, like this:

```
[_hwlayer bullets]
```

This does not require importing the header.